# How to change the attributes values of multiple cloned HTML elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to change the attribute values of cloned elements in jQuery to new values, but somehow my script doesn't work. Please have a look at my HTML code which I am trying to clone.

```
            <div id="process_operands" class="process_input">
                <select name="process_operands">
                    <option name="PO" value="Process_Name">Process Name</option>
                    <option name="PO" value="Process_Path">Process Abspath</option>
                    <option name="PO" value="Process_Signature">Process Signature</option>
                    <option name="PO" value="Process_Acl">Process ACL</option>
                    <option name="PO" value="Process_Checksum">Process Checksum</option>
                    <option name="PO" value="Process_Type">Process Type</option>
                </select> &nbsp             
                <input type=text name="PO_value" maxlength="5000">
            </div>
            <div id="Padditionalselects"></div>
            <p class="add_PO">Add more</p>
```

My JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//var counter = 0;
$(".add_PO").click(function(){
  //  var counter=counter+1;
        var selectclone = $("#process_operands").clone(true)
            .append($('<a class="delete" href="#">Remove</a>'))
            .appendTo("#Padditionalselects");           

        selectclone.find('select').attr('name', 'process_operands1');
        selectclone.find('input').attr('name', 'PO_value1');
    });

    $("body").on('click',".delete", function() {
        $(this).closest(".process_input").remove();
    }); 
    });
```

Can someone help me out? Is there a better way?

Question 2: Once, my above code works, I want to create a variable with counter assigned 0. Each time, a clone happens, I want my "name" attribute's value to be process_operands1, process_operands2 so on.

I hope my questions are clear.

Comment: Where is `clone` initialized? Do you mean to be storing the `$("#process_operands")...` result in a variable named `clone`?

Comment: Don't for get to change the clone's id, so you are not duplicating ids.

Comment: you can use selector jquery in "class" or "id". example $("#process_operands").html().

Comment: @TypeIA  All I am trying to do is clone the entire div with id=process_operands an then append it to another div with id=PadditionalSelects.

Comment: @Taplar I am not using the id attribute for further manipulation. Hence, I didn't modify it. But, I added new name attributes with which I am working and which I seem no able to make it work.

Comment: @SushmaMynampati Understood, I'm just pointing out (as are others) that your posted code uses an undefined variable `clone` and I'm guessing you forgot to declare and assign it from the result of the `clone()` function call.

Comment: Regardless of you changing it or not, this logic as is will insert multiple elements with the same id, which is invalid according to the HTML Standard.  https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-id

Comment: @TypeIA Please find my edit. I included a var selectclone which will contain the result of the clone. Does this helps? Is that what you are pointing out? I am sorry, I am very new to jQuery

Comment: You can check my answer. It works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to assign the cloned element to a variable, in order to manipulate the cloned element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 // Cloned elements count
 var counter = 0;
 
 $(".add_PO").click(function(){
  
  // Increment the cloned element count
  counter++;
  
  // Clone the element and assign it to a variable
  var clone = $("#process_operands").clone(true)
   .append($('<a class="delete" href="#">Remove</a>'))
   .appendTo("#Padditionalselects");
  
  // Modify cloned element, using the counter variable
  clone.find('select').attr('name', 'process_operands'+counter);
  clone.find('input').attr('name', 'PO_value'+counter);
  
 });
 
 $("body").on('click',".delete", function() {
  $(this).closest(".process_input").remove();
  counter--; // Modify the counter
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="process_operands" class="process_input">
 <select name="process_operands">
  <option name="PO" value="Process_Name">Process Name</option>
  <option name="PO" value="Process_Path">Process Abspath</option>
  <option name="PO" value="Process_Signature">Process Signature</option>
  <option name="PO" value="Process_Acl">Process ACL</option>
  <option name="PO" value="Process_Checksum">Process Checksum</option>
  <option name="PO" value="Process_Type">Process Type</option>
 </select> &nbsp
 <input type=text name="PO_value" maxlength="5000">
</div>
<div id="Padditionalselects"></div>
<p class="add_PO">Add more</p>
```

As a suggestion, it will be better to apply names that you can use as arrays server-side for your inputs. Instead of having `process_operands` as name, you could name the field `process_operands[]` so you could access the variable as an array server-side, as i mentioned, and you could skip changing the inputs names also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To make sure, the attributes are changed, I wrote a small RESTful webservice, which takes all the form parameters. I am not able to get the value of cloned select list with the process_operands_1. I am using @FormParam(process_operands_1). Can you let me know why is that?

Comment: You need it to be `process_operands_1` and not `process_operands1` as you mentioned in your question?

Comment: Yes, I modified my web service accordingly to process_operands_1. Still doesn't work. How to make sure, the attributes are modified?

Comment: You can inspect the HTML. The code is there with the name attributes changes as expected. Maybe you can print all the form params to see if they are all there. Is the container of the cloned elements inside the form element that submits the data to the server?

Comment: Be aware that i modified my code a while ago to match your inputs names requirements (`process_operand1` for example). If you are using the latest version of my code, you should expect `process_operand1` server side.

Comment: Got it. Yes, it is modified, but I am not able to access it. I did print all the form params already, and its showing null for process_operands_1 and PO_value_1. To ans your question, yes. the container of cloned elements is inside form element.

Comment: I did a quick test using php on my localhost, and all the data is sent to the server as expected. Maybe yoy should open a new question on that issue. Sorry i can't help you with that. I should need more info in order to be able to reproduce you issue.

Comment: Yeah. sure. Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this

$(document).ready(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $(".add_PO").click(function(){
        counter=counter+1;
        var $clone = $("#process_operands").clone(true)
            .append($('<a class="delete" href="#">Remove</a>'))
            .attr("id","process_operands"+counter);           
        $clone.find('select').attr('name', 'process_operands'+counter);
        $clone.find('input').attr('name', 'PO_value1'+counter);
        $clone.appendTo($("#Padditionalselects"));
    });
    $("body").on('click',".delete", function() {
    $(this).closest(".process_input").remove();
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery example by name:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="process_operands">
  <option name="PO" value="Process_Name">Process Name</option>
  <option name="PO" value="Process_Path">Process Abspath</option>
  <option name="PO" value="Process_Signature">Process Signature</option>
  <option name="PO" value="Process_Acl">Process ACL</option>
  <option name="PO" value="Process_Checksum">Process Checksum</option>
  <option name="PO" value="Process_Type">Process Type</option>
</select>
<script>
$("option[name='PO']").each(function(){
   $(this).attr('value', '1')
});
</script>
```

[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/yrxctbs1/1/)
on this case only set attr value for all options you can set css, or other attr, you can use a selector (name, id, css..etc..)
[Look the doc Jquery Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Comment: I quite didn't understand what you are trying to say. I am new to jQuery.